# Truncate EasyTable in Azure App Services C# Universal App

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, windows-10-universal

I can't seem to find a method that would help me truncate an easytable created in Azure App Services.

What would be the most efficient way to truncate a table?

I am currently using C#/XAML for Windows Universal Apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the client. You can either delete rows manually using a SQL query or use the method described below from a custom API or table script:

```
var table = req.azureMobile.tables('tableName').truncate().then(function () {
    res.send('Table truncated')
})
```